# Automate deploy to playapps.net

Tags: playframework

I am currently using playapps.net to host a play framework application.
Every time I deploy I have to enter my username, password select options for stopping starting and backing up the server.

Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are going to have to switch hosts anyway [playapps.net is closing down](http://www.playapps.net/). They recommend [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) or you could try [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com/) which looks cool and [supports play](http://blog.jelastic.com/2012/02/13/play-in-the-cloud/)